# Writing to the real STDOUT after System.setOut

Tags: java

I'm trying to intercept System.out and System.err, but maintain the ability to write to the original streams directly when necessary.

```
PrintStream ps = System.out;
System.setOut(new MyMagicPrintStream());
ps.println("foo");
```

Unfortunately, the details of the System class' implementation means that in my example, "foo" gets sent to `MyMagicPrintStream` instead of the real `stdout`.

Does anyone know how to get references to the real/original `OutputStreams`?

Thanks.

*PS: This will otherwise result in a StackOverflowError <-- for SEO.*

Answer (score 29, accepted):

try this:

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out))
```

Comment: (I didn't know you could do that!)  However, there is a potential problem with this approach.  If some other part of your application is using the original System.out `PrintStream` object, then output to stdout from the two streams could be randomly interleaved.  Using a single stream object will be less prone to this.

Comment: I think it won't because PrintStream doesn't have buffers so data should come directly to stdout, right?

Comment: I knew there must be a way to get the original file descriptor.  This is perfect.  Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Try something like this :

```
  PrintStream original = new PrintStream(System.out);

  // replace the System.out, here I redirect to NUL
  System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("NUL:")));
  System.out.println("bar");  // no output

  // the original stream is still available 
  original.println("foo");  // output to stdout
```

Comment: How is this any different to what the OP posted?

Comment: The OP keep a reference to out which will be change by the setOut(). In my answer, I create a new Stream from the current out which will not be affected by the setOut(). At least, that's how I understand it :-)

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed.  I ran it through the jvm fully expecting it to fail as my OP, but it works.  Congrats, that's impressive.  Thanks!

Comment: Save the original stream and use it later.

Answer (score 1):

```
PrintStream original = System.out;
System.setOut(new MyMagicPrintStream());

// This will print to MyMagicPrintStream();
System.out.println("foo for MyMagicPrintStream");


System.setOut(original);

// This will print to original print stream;
System.out.println("foo for original print stream (stdout)");
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

`PrintStream original = new PrintStream(System.out);` basically wraps the existing reference - so if `System.setOut()` was changing it - there should be no difference. That's probably an issue with particular JVM, but I would rather guess that something was wrong with the MyMagicPrintStream, or the code writing to the stdout. Actually the following piece of code does exactly what is expected on Sun 1.6.0_20-b02 for Windows:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class SystemOutTest {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        PrintStream ps = System.out;
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("stdout.log")));

        System.out.println("foo");  
        ps.println("bar");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

"foo" goes to stdout.log, "bar" to the console.

Also, if you need to access the original stdin / out assigned of JVM startup - you can use `System.console();` (just remember - it can be `null`!)