# Write a console message from Eclipse to a file

Tags: java, file-io, io, selenium-webdriver

How to write a console message from Eclipse to a file?

Please review it and I would appreciate if any one give the solution.
My sample program is given below

this is the console message:

```
Invalid Excel Path Specified "+path
```

---

```
      try {                      
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
          String lineFromInput = in.readLine();

          PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("C:/Error.txt"));            
          System.setOut(out);       
                       out.close();
       }
          catch(IOException e1) {
            System.out.println("Error during reading/writing");
       }     
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to change 
`FileOutputStream("C:/Error.txt")`

to

`FileOutputStream("C:\\Error.txt")`

as Juned Ahsan mentioned. In addition, if you need to write the text that you get from console into

`Error.txt`

you need to add a line like

`System.out.println(lineFromInput);`   after

`System.setOut(out);`

line, where you set the default output location.

Comment: now i changed ma code like u said ,but it didnt work                                        try {
        
    
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
           String lineFromInput = in.readLine();

           PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Error.txt"));            
           System.setOut(out); 
           System.out.println(lineFromInput);
           out.close();
     }
        catch(IOException e1) {
          System.out.println("Error during reading/writing");
     }

Comment: @pinkpanther i didnt get errors.but its not writing the console output to the file

Comment: @Anna, well are you sure that you have permission to create a file under `C:\` root? Is `Error.txt` being created but empty?

Comment: @Alpay ,Ys the file is created but empty...:(

Comment: I tried the same code and it writes the string I provide from console perfectly. The program should hang when it sees `in.readLine()`. There it waits for an input from console. I suggest you to debug the program and see if lineFromInput string contains the value you enter from command line.

Comment: Actually the thing is that the message on console is generated after running the code and after that this message should be printed on a file .is it possible??

Comment: I think you need something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340342/java-writing-to-the-real-stdout-after-system-setout)

Answer (score 0):

```
PrintStream out = null;
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    System.in));
            String lineFromInput = in.readLine();

            out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("C:/Error.txt"));
            System.setOut(out);
            System.out.println(lineFromInput);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error during reading/writing");
        } finally {
            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //ignore
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Anna Have you entered your text on console and pressed enter?

Comment: Macon ,Actually the thing is that the message on console is generated after running the code and after that this message should be printed on a file .is it possible??

Comment: Macon ,I am doing automation testing using selenium webdriver using java. So here the input file is in c:/ folder. and what i am trying to implement is if the file path is not correct it will generate a message "Invalid Excel Path Specified "+path" and i want to take this message from console and print on a txt file. the message is generated during runtime and at the same time i want to write it on txt file.is it clear MAcon?

Comment: hmmmmm. Then I suggest you move this to initial startup of your application. For this is a one time setup for overall application useage.

System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("C:/Error.txt")));

Comment: @Anna I also developed a selenium based Java application which  provided output on a Dockable TextArea for the users to give rich experience, on what application is working on, along with log directory , logging all these for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: Can i get this runtime message to a text file at the same time?

Comment: yes that's doable, You add a JTextArea, and keep on append() it. 

Moreover interms of logging You could also use Logger Frameworks like log4j , where you can use log4j.propertise to control where you want the output to be ridden. Than using a static place like 'C;\Error.txt'