# Java redirect stdout to file and back to console

Tags: java, stdout

I have a java swing application that I am trying to give the user the ability to switch stdout back and forth from file to console.  This is meant to be a toggle.  I can toggle on file, but am not able to toggle back to console.  When I toggle back, I do not get any output on either.

```
    private void btnPrefsConsoleActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                                
    {                                                    
        outputTo = "console";                                   // Set output to console

***** FIX ***** comment next 2 lines and insert 3rd
        pStream = System.out;
        System.setOut(pStream);                                 // Set output back to console
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out)));
***** FIX *****
        btnPrefsConsole.setSelected(true);                      // Turn on console
        btnPrefsSysout.setSelected(false);                      // Turn off sysout
        monitorPrefs.put(MONITOROUTPUT, outputTo);              // Set in prefs
    }                                               

    private void btnPrefsSysoutActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                               
    {                                                   
        outputTo = "sysout";                                    // Set output to console
        btnPrefsConsole.setSelected(false);                     // Turn off console
        btnPrefsSysout.setSelected(true);                       // Turn on sysout

//              Switch System.out to file 
        try
        {
            pStream = new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(dbPath + "/sysout.txt")),true);
            System.setOut(pStream);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(DRHandicapMonitor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        monitorPrefs.put(MONITOROUTPUT, outputTo);              // Set in prefs
    }
```

EDIT:

I have tried solutions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339499/resetting-standard-output-stream?noredirect=1&lq=1):

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out)));
```

and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340342/java-writing-to-the-real-stdout-after-system-setout).

None of which seemed to work.

Comment: You realize `System.setOut(System.out);` does nothing, right?

Comment: I wouldn't have it in there if I thought it did nothing.  I have read most of the threads here relating to this including the one you referenced.  It, along with many others did not work for me.  System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out))); replacing System.setOut(pStream);   Did not work.  Same result.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion.  I tried 'System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out)));' and it did not work for.  I just tried it again and it is working fine.  I don't know what I did different.